# What is "String..."

Tags: java, android, string

I am would like to know what the `String...` keyword is. From my understanding it is a pseudonym for `String[]`. However it does not seem to behave the same way. For example I have a server that will send the string `"<PING>\n"` to a client. The client processes this message with the method:

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        arrayList.add(values[0]);
        // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
        // from server was added to the list
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        parseMessage(values);
    }
```

Then for debugging purposes I print to console the items in values in `parseMessage()`:

```
private void parseMessage(String... theMessage)
    {
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");

        for (int i=0; i<theMessage.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(theMessage[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("-----------------------------");

        if (theMessage[0].equals("<PING>"))
        {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage("<PING>");
        }
        else if (theMessage[0].equals("<PING>\n"))
        {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage("<PING>");
        }
        else
        {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage(theMessage[0]);
        }
    }
```

This gives me the expected output on the first message I receive:

```
02-07 14:39:51.277: I/System.out(10823): -----------------------------
02-07 14:39:51.277: I/System.out(10823): <PING>
02-07 14:39:51.277: I/System.out(10823): -----------------------------
```

However the second time the client recieves `"<PING>\n"` the console displays:

```
02-07 14:40:01.298: I/System.out(10823): -----------------------------
02-07 14:40:01.298: I/System.out(10823): ��<PING>
02-07 14:40:01.298: I/System.out(10823): -----------------------------
```

I do not understand why it displays the symbols `�`. The second time it receives `"<PING>\n"` I expect it to display:

```
-----------------------------
<PING>
<PING>
-----------------------------
```

Can someone please explain the discrepancy between the expected output and actual output?

Comment: What makes you think those characters aren't in the input somehow?

Comment: I print on the server what it is sending and those characters aren't included. I think they are artifacts from `arrayList`.

Comment: Array lists don't have any "artifacts". Those characters are part of whatever send/receive process you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`...` is a [variable argument list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Inside the function it may be treated as an array.

Comment: This is answered in question itself, any idea why question marks there in output?

Comment: It is not clear where do you get the data from, and the question marks are probably some of the input. You might need to use some other encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The `...` in general stands for *variable number of arguments*

So you can have a method with variable number of arguments of any type.

The strange symbol you're seeing in your output has nothing to do with this. You may try to see what's inside with Arrays.toString() method:

```
$ cat A.java 
import java.util.Arrays;


public class A {
    public void example( String ... args ) {
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( args ) );
    }
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        A a = new A();
        a.example("ping", "pong\n");
        a.example("That's", "all", "folks");
    }
}

$ java A
[ping, pong
]
[That's, all, folks]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call the function, it turns the list of comma separated arguments into an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

`String...` is indeed a syntaxic sugar that replaces `String[]` and allows you to pass a undefined numbers of arguments to a method.

Example :

```
public void withArray(String[] values){ ... }
withArray(new String[] {"a", "b"});

public void withVarArgs(String... values) { ... }
withVarArgs("a", "b");
```

Variable args allow you to pass arguments directly, skipping `new String[]` declaration.